# android oreo/pie - paho mqtt Unable to start activity in background

Tags: mqtt, paho, android-9.0-pie

I'm trying to solve paho mqtt running on android pie(9.0).

I'm running my mqtt connection in Service class (return START_STICKY) and connecting to UI with bind... All is working perfectly fine but WHAT IS NOT WORKING is 
when app is killed, Service and mqtt connection stops. Mqtt 
`AlarmPingSender` stop working.. Tried to test it on Nougat(7.0) and it's working perfectly fine.

Is there a solution to make mqtt paho library working on new version of Android?

**LOGCAT:**

```
2019-03-22 02:35:08.854 12651-12651/com.example.dominik.smarthome2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dominik.smarthome2, PID: 12651
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dominik.smarthome2/com.example.dominik.smarthome2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.dominik.smarthome2/.MyService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{ee07604 u0a297 TPSL idle procs:1 proclist:12651, seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.dominik.smarthome2/.MyService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{ee07604 u0a297 TPSL idle procs:1 proclist:12651, seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1666)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1611)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:677)
    at com.example.dominik.smarthome2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:122)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 8.0 has introduced [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) and thus you should use `startForegroundService()` instead of `startService()` to run a *Foreground Service* with visible notification:

[image: diagram]

Comment: I tried to run mqtt connection without Service but Paho library returns the same error. So that means Paho alose use Service and not foregroundService?

Comment: Paho MQTT client is not an Android Service.